# App deployed to heroku last night, today all of a sudden app not found

Tags: heroku

I'm guessing there is a really simple answer for this.  Everything was fine last night, I wake up this morning and go to my page on heroku and it says app not found.  Curiously when I go to my heroku dashboard, it says app is sleeping for about 9 hours due to inactivity.  I then click wake, and it just reverts back to sleeping when i refresh the dashboard.

Comment: https://status.heroku.com/

Answer (score 0):

There have been API problems on Heroku today so there's a chance that your application was affected - I would suggest opening a support ticket directly with Heroku.

Comment: "it says my app is sleeping for about 9 hours due to inactivity".  I guess my question is what does this mean, and how do I fix it?